# WARNING cloudWatch scrape failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, prometheus-alertmanager, helm3

I configured prometheus cloudwatch exporter helm  chart to fetch SFTP Transfer Service metrics to prometheus/grafana. On deploying the helm chart, while checking the pod logs I found these warnings which are coming very frequently. But its not stopping cloudwatch exporter to pull the metrics from the cloudwatch metrics.

```
    2022-07-14T16:16:11.818315387Z Jul 14, 2022 4:16:11 PM io.prometheus.cloudwatch.CloudWatchCollector collect
2022-07-14T16:16:11.818365904Z WARNING: CloudWatch scrape failed
2022-07-14T16:16:11.818371728Z software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatch.model.CloudWatchException: Rate exceeded (Service: CloudWatch, Status Code: 400, Request ID: aaa68484-bf4e-4fca-8d82-93d53b9134e2)
```

This is my values.yaml which has below metrics configuration:

```
- aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: BytesIn
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: BytesOut
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: FilesIn
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: FilesOut
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: OnUploadExecutionsStarted
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: OnUploadExecutionsFailed
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
       tag_selections:
         "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
       resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
       resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
    - aws_namespace: AWS/Transfer
      aws_metric_name: OnUploadExecutionsSuccess
      aws_dimensions: [ServerId]
      aws_tag_select:
        tag_selections:
          "tl:prefix": ["dev"]
        resource_type_selection: "transfer:server"
        resource_id_dimension: ServerId
      aws_statistics: [Average]
      use_get_metric_data: true
```

Can someone please guide me here what am I missing?

Comment: The error says `Rate exceeded` -- It looks like your app is calling the CloudWatch API too many times. Might help: [CloudWatch service quotas - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Is there a way I can check which APP is calling which Cloudwatch API that's making this error?

Comment: You could look in AWS CloudTrail, which records all API requests being made in the AWS Account.

Comment: On checking the Cloudtrail, I can't see any info regarding Scrape error. There are lots of other API's info there but not specific to GetMetricStatistics/GetMetricData. Any suggestions? @JohnRotenstein